# adding and removing text to a span populated from a dropdown

Tags: javascript

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrFent/n5c1teyw/):

The end result I am wanting is that once you make a selection from each dropdown, the selection appears in the first line of text, and then get's reversed in the 2nd line of text. However, the apostrophe S needs to remain in the first spot. So for example, if you selected "Mother" from the first dropdown, and "Father" from the 2nd drop down, the two lines of text should look like this:

My Mother's Father 
My Father's Mother

I don't know how to swap the apostrophe S so that it remains so that it comes first.

I tried using:

```
document.getElementById('third').innerHTML = strUser2 + "'s";
```

but that causes the apostrophe s to appear before I have anything selected.

Answer (score 1):

That's because to run two functions before selecting. Remove them and try.

```js
function functionOne() {
  var e = document.getElementById("dropdown_1");
  var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById('first').innerHTML = strUser;
  document.getElementById('fourth').innerHTML = strUser.replace("'s", '');
}
document.getElementById("dropdown_1").onchange = functionOne;

function functionTwo() {

  var e = document.getElementById("dropdown_2");
  var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var strUser2 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

  document.getElementById('second').innerHTML = strUser;
  document.getElementById('third').innerHTML = strUser2+ "'s";
}

document.getElementById("dropdown_2").onchange = functionTwo;
```

```css
span#first,
span#second,
span#third,
span#fourth {
  min-width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
  height: 18px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<select class="text_select" id="dropdown_1" name="dropdown_1">    
   <option value="">- Select -</option>  
   <option value="Father's">Father's</option>  
   <option value="Mother's">Mother's</option>  
   <option value="Sister's">Sister's</option>
   <option value="Brother's">Brother's</option>  

   </select>

<select class="text_select" id="dropdown_2" name="dropdown_2">    
   <option value="">- Select -</option>  
   <option value="Father">Father</option>  
   <option value="Mother">Mother</option>  
   <option value="Sister">Sister</option>
   <option value="Brother">Brother</option>  
   </select>

<br /><br />
<label class="row_1">My <span id="first"></span> <span id="second"></span></label>
<br />
<label class="row_2">My <span id="third"></span> <span id="fourth"></span></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change the values in the `option` tags, but keep the display the same. Ex: `<option value="Father">Father's</option>`
Then append `'s` after the values you want to have `'s`.

Also don't execute each function by default, **only** execute them `onchange`. That way you'll never get something like `'s` when the page loads.

I would then make sure `- Select -` is the first option (`selected`) for both `option` tags, but make them `disabled` so the user cannot choose those as options.

**--note--**

I would strongly recommend using `textContent` as supposed to `innerHTML` to avoid possible code injection, depending on what you're using this for.

```js
function functionOne(){
   var e = document.getElementById("dropdown_1");
   var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
   document.getElementById('first').textContent = strUser + "'s";
   document.getElementById('fourth').textContent = strUser;
   }
       document.getElementById("dropdown_1").onchange = functionOne;

   function functionTwo(){

   var e = document.getElementById("dropdown_2");
   var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
   var strUser2 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
   
   document.getElementById('second').textContent = strUser;
   document.getElementById('third').textContent = strUser2 + "'s";
   }
    
       document.getElementById("dropdown_2").onchange = functionTwo;
```

```css
span#first, span#second, span#third, span#fourth{
  min-width:40px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-bottom:solid 1px;
  height:18px;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

```html
<select class="text_select" id="dropdown_1" name="dropdown_1">    
   <option value="" disabled selected>- Select -</option>  
   <option value="Father">Father's</option>  
   <option value="Mother">Mother's</option>  
   <option value="Sister">Sister's</option>
   <option value="Brother">Brother's</option>  

   </select>

   <select class="text_select" id="dropdown_2" name="dropdown_2">    
   <option value="" disabled selected>- Select -</option>  
   <option value="Father">Father</option>  
   <option value="Mother">Mother</option>  
   <option value="Sister">Sister</option>
   <option value="Brother">Brother</option>  
   </select>

   <br /><br />
   <label class="row_1">My <span id="first"></span> <span id="second"></span></label>
   <br />
   <label class="row_2">My <span id="third"></span> <span id="fourth"></span></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

Remove the apostrophe's from the list values and add on the string only if defined:

```
document.getElementById('first').innerHTML = strUser+(strUser ? "'s" : "");
document.getElementById('third').innerHTML = strUser2+(strUser2 ? "'s" : "");
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n5c1teyw/14/)

EDIT - New solution:

Full code solution keeping the 2 lines from populating until both dropdowns are selected, as requested:

```js
var firstSelect = false;
       var secondSelect = false;
       var dd1 = document.getElementById("dropdown_1");
       var dd2 = document.getElementById("dropdown_2");
    
     function clearAllContainers(){
           document.getElementById('first').innerHTML = '';
           document.getElementById('second').innerHTML = '';
           document.getElementById('third').innerHTML = '';
           document.getElementById('fourth').innerHTML = '';
          }
    
       function updateAllContainers(){
              var strUser = dd1.options[dd1.selectedIndex].value;
               document.getElementById('first').innerHTML = strUser+(strUser ? "'s" : "");
               document.getElementById('fourth').innerHTML = strUser; 
                
               var strUser2 = dd2.options[dd2.selectedIndex].value;
               document.getElementById('second').innerHTML = strUser2;
               document.getElementById('third').innerHTML = strUser2+(strUser2 ? "'s" : "");
                
          }
    
       function functionOne(){
              if(dd1.options[dd1.selectedIndex].value){
               firstSelect = true;
              }else{
               firstSelect = false;
              }
              if(secondSelect && dd1.options[dd1.selectedIndex].value != ''){
          updateAllContainers();
              }else{
               clearAllContainers();
              }
    
          }
       functionOne()
           document.getElementById("dropdown_1").onchange = functionOne;
    
       function functionTwo(){
              if(dd2.options[dd2.selectedIndex].value){
               secondSelect = true;
              }else{
               secondSelect = false;
              }
              if(firstSelect && dd2.options[dd2.selectedIndex].value != ''){
          updateAllContainers();
              }else{
               clearAllContainers();
              }
          }
       functionTwo()
        
           document.getElementById("dropdown_2").onchange = functionTwo;
```

```html
<select class="text_select" id="dropdown_1" name="dropdown_1">    
  <option value="">- Select -</option>  
  <option value="Father">Father</option>  
  <option value="Mother">Mother</option>  
  <option value="Sister">Sister</option>
  <option value="Brother">Brother</option>  

  </select>

  <select class="text_select" id="dropdown_2" name="dropdown_2">    
  <option value="">- Select -</option>  
  <option value="Father">Father</option>  
  <option value="Mother">Mother</option>  
  <option value="Sister">Sister</option>
  <option value="Brother">Brother</option>  
  </select>

  <br /><br />
  <label class="row_1">My <span id="first"></span> <span id="second"></span></label>
  <br />
  <label class="row_2">My <span id="third"></span> <span id="fourth"></span></label>
```

Updated fiddle for final solution is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n5c1teyw/54/).

Comment: Thank you @AmmoPT. Now for it to look a bit cleaner, how would I keep the 2 lines from populating until both dropdowns are selected?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your Javascript file on JSFiddle. The solution is very simple. First you'll have to remove  ***apostrophe s*** from the content of `<span id="fourth"></span>`

You can do that easily by slicing off last two characters from the content of that span. Here is how you need to do it.

```
document.getElementById('fourth').innerHTML = strUser.slice(0, strUser.length - 2);
```

Now, the next part is to add ***apostrophe s*** in the content of `<span id="third"></span>`.

But you'll have to make sure that if the content of the span is empty then it should not append ***apostrophe s***.

For that you can check whether on not the content is empty and if not empty then you can append ***apostrophe s***.

Here is how you can do it.

```
document.getElementById('third').innerHTML = (strUser)? strUser + '\'s':strUser;
```

Here is the overall modified code of your Javascript file.

```
function functionOne(){
            var e = document.getElementById("dropdown_1");
            var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;    
            document.getElementById('first').innerHTML = strUser;
            document.getElementById('fourth').innerHTML = strUser.slice(0, strUser.length - 2);
            }
            functionOne();
                document.getElementById("dropdown_1").onchange = functionOne;

            function functionTwo(){

            var e = document.getElementById("dropdown_2");
            var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            //var strUser2 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

            document.getElementById('second').innerHTML = strUser;
            document.getElementById('third').innerHTML = (strUser)? strUser + '\'s':strUser;
            }
            functionTwo()

                document.getElementById("dropdown_2").onchange = functionTwo;
```